# Install software from the host on VM using powershell

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I need to install an application from the host machine on chosen VM.
I am Using Virtual Machine Manager and I tried this lines but they did not work.

1) `Get-SCVirtualMachine`

2) `Start-SCVirtualMachine -VM Name`

and them I tried to copy the  file on VM and start the installation process but it did not work

3)`Copy-VMFile -Name DSC01 -SourcePath .\1.2.0.0.zip -DestinationPath ‘C:\Users\Public\1.2.0.0.zip’ -FileSource Host -CreateFullPath`
and

4)`Start-Process "setup.exe" -ArgumentList "/s" -Wait`

Does anybody have any idea how to do it?

Comment: What exactly didn't work?

Comment: I cannot copy file from host machine to VM and I cannot start installation process...

Comment: Any error ? Please include the error messages in your question (you can edit it).

Comment: Copy-VMFile : The term 'Copy-VMFile' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1        -technically you i cannot use Copy-VMFile for SCVM... so that´s why I am wondering how can I copy the file to VM and install it on VM

Comment: First run 'gcm copy-vmfile' on your host and check if the cmdlet is available ? Looks like it's there in Windows 2012 R2, what OS are you using ? You may need to import HyperV module first before https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848559%28v=wps.630%29.aspx.

Comment: @zerocool18 I am using Windows 10 Enterprise . Yes We are using windows 2012 R2 to manage all virtual machines

Comment: okay, what ouput does "gcm copy-vmfile" gives ?

Answer (score 1):

Your commands look right.  It could be that guest file copy isn't enabled -- it's disabled by default.  Check to make sure guest services are enabled for the virtual machine ([instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/user_guide/managing_ics#enable-or-disable-integration-services-using-powershell)).

Get-VMIntegrationService -VMName DSC01

Enable-VMIntegrationService -VMName DSC01 -Name "Guest Service Interface"

Server 16 and the technical previews let you do this with PowerShell's Copy-Item, given guest credentials :).  Check it out [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/user_guide/vmsession#copy-files-with-new-pssession-and-copy-item).

Comment: First, create VM Hyper-V using a ISO Windows 2016. Then, How-to Install-WindowsFeature and apps software (chocolatey) using Remote Powershell, against Virtual Machine (Windows 2016) in Hyper-V (in Windows 10) ?